# Getting desired space between table and header

Tags: tables, floats

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
& & & & \\
& & (a) & & \\
\end{tabular}
\hspace{7mm}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
& & & & \\
& & (b) & & \\
\end{tabular}
\hspace{7mm}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
& & & & \\
& & (c) & & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

I generated three tables that are horizontally next to each other. Below each table I had the headings (a), (b), (c), and I created an empty line in each of the tables so that the headings are not too close to the table entries. However, now they are a little too far, and I want to move them up. How can I do that?

Note: I typed (a), (b), (c) manually because I wanted to avoid the subfigure/subfig packages, which are deprecated.

Comment: subfig package is not deprecated, as far as I know. With it solution is simple and elegant, isn't it?

Comment: Instead of a blank line you can use \\\[2ex] (for example) and adjust the distance as finely as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of package `subfig` gives nice result:

[image]

but if you persist to not use `subfig` and all other his benefits (like referencing subtables), than you can do with nested tables, where the vertical space between them and "captions" is also simple to adjust. For where, see code below:

[image]

Code for both cases are simple (I use `table` environment instead of `figure`, as you can see above):

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=colon,
            position=below]{caption} % 08_03_2014

    \begin{document}
% the first case
\begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Add caption}
    \label{tab:mytable}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 
\end{tabular}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 
\end{tabular}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 
\end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

%t he second cas    
\begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{tabular}   \\[3pt]% <--- here you can set distance  
                       % between tables and subcaptions
(a) &   (b) &   (c)
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using minipage:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{width=\0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
& & & & \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{(a)}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{7mm}
\begin{minipage}{width=\0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
& & & & \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{(b)}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{7mm}
\begin{minipage}{width=\0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
& & & & \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{(c)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```